# MVVM Button Content Properties not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have this code

```
private string _contentButtonDisplaySearch;

public string ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch
{
    get { return _contentButtonDisplaySearch; }
    set
    {
        if (_contentButtonDisplaySearch == value)
            return;
        _contentButtonDisplaySearch = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonDisplaySearch" Content="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="164" Height="39"/>
```

The content on my button does not change when I change the value of _contentButtonDisplaySearch. What am I doing wrong?

this is how I change the value _contentButtonDisplaySearch

```
private void OKRun()
{
    _contentButtonDisplaySearch = "ChangeContent";
}
```

INotifyPropertyChanged

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
        }

        #endregion
```

I set DataContext this does not work

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonDisplaySearch"  Content="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch}" DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="164" Height="39"/>
```

DataContext set in my view

```
 this._view.SetDataContext(this);
            this._view.ShowIView();
```

when there is loading MainWindow, when i set _contentButtonDisplaySearch, Button content change, but then when I try to change nothing happens

Comment: You need to change `ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch`, not `_contentButtonDisplaySearch` otherwise `OnPropertyChanged()` won't get called.

Comment: are you able to see your Text as content of your Button if you set a default text?

Answer (score 4):

Modify property directly instead of its value. If you modify variable `set` will not be triggered and `OnPropertyChange();` event will not be fired.

**Try assigning value directly via property:**

```
private void OKRun()
  {
     ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch = "ChangeContent";
  }
```

Your `<Button/>` in `xaml` should have `UpdateSourceTrigger` property set as such:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Also, try adding `DataContext` there are plently of ways to do so. You can try adding it by overriding `OnStartup();` event in `App.xaml.cs` file.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainWindow _window = new MainWindow();
        ClassWhereIsYourPropertyStored _vM = new ClassWhereIsYourPropertyStored();
        _window.DataContext = _vM;
        _window.Show();
  }
```

Comment: @VladimirKombarov Have you set `DataContext`?

Comment: Is there need DataContext?

Comment: @VladimirKombarov Yes you need to set `DataContext` if you wish to Bind `properties` value.

Comment: @VladimirKombarov If it has an error line beneath `Content="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch,` then it means that you have not set `DataContext` properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is really interested me why `Content` property of `Button` control  is not actually updated. And I've found the reason why. Cause `string` type is immutable, if condition `if(_contentButtonDisplaySearch!= value)` is not appropriate cause we have just new `string` object and this newly created `string` object will be always equal to the `value` of property:

Your view model:

```
public class YourViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    int _contentButtonDisplaySearch = 1;
    public string ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch
    {
        get { return _contentButtonDisplaySearch; }
        set
        {
            //if(_contentButtonDisplaySearch!= value)//this condition is not appropriate 
            //cause we have just new `string` object and this newly created
            //`string` object will be always equal to the `value` of property
            _contentButtonDisplaySearch = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch");
        }
    }

    private ICommand _changeCountCommand;
    public ICommand ChangeCountCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeCountCommand == null)
            {
                _changeCountCommand = new RelayCommand(
                p => ChangeViewModel(),
                p => true);
            }
            return _changeCountCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ChangeViewModel()
    {
        ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch++;            
    }  
}
```

ViewModelBase class:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Your xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
     <local:YourViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
     <StackPanel>
      <Button Content="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch}" Command="{Binding ChangeCountCommand}"></Button>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch}"/>        
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

or at the code behind of view:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication.DataBinding
{
        public partial class DataContextSample : Window
        {
                public DataContextSample()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: you need to set DataContext to your form. As your View(your Window) and ViewModel is not connected so your view cannot take data from viewmodel. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

My View

```
 public partial class MainWindow : IView
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ShowIView()
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        public void ShowViewAsModal()
        {

            this.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void SetDataContext(object dataContext)
        {
            this.DataContext = dataContext;

        }
```

Iview

```
 public interface IView
    {
        void ShowIView();
        void ShowViewAsModal();
        void SetDataContext(object dataContext);

    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class PriceListViewModels<TViewType> : IViewModel where TViewType : IView,  new () 
    {
        private readonly IView _view;

        private readonly PriceListModel _modelPriceListModel;
        private readonly PriceModel _modelPriceModel;
        private readonly NewServInPriceListModel _modelNewServInPriceListModel;

        public ObservableCollection<PriceList> PriceListObservableCollection { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Price> PriceObservableCollection { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<NewServInPriceList> NewServObServableCollection { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand CommandSave { get; private set; }


        // создаем объект ICollection View, для отображения и фильтрации данных в Datagrid
        public ICollectionView collview { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<bool> Colec { get; set; }


        #region fields
        private string _textBoxSearch;  // переменная которая связана с TextBoxSearch во View
        private DateTime _dateTimeBeginPriceList; 
        private DateTime _dateTimeEndPriceList;
        private int _selectedIndexListBox;
        private string _textBoxComment;
        private string _contentButtonDisplaySearch;

        // переменные для выбора типов оплаты
        private bool _omsIsChecked;
        private bool _dmsIsChecked;
        private bool _budshetIsChecked;
        private bool _platnoIsChecked;

        private bool _displayRadioButton;
        private bool _searchRadionButton;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public PriceListViewModels()
        {
            this._view = new TViewType();

            this._modelPriceListModel = new PriceListModel();
            this.PriceListObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<PriceList>(this._modelPriceListModel.GetService());

            this._modelPriceModel = new PriceModel();
            this.PriceObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Price>(this._modelPriceModel.GetPrice());

            this._modelNewServInPriceListModel = new NewServInPriceListModel();
            this.NewServObServableCollection = new ObservableCollection<NewServInPriceList>(this._modelNewServInPriceListModel.GetNewServ());
            this.CommandSave = new RelayCommand(o => this.OKRun());


            // присваиваем collview observable collection 
            collview = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(NewServObServableCollection);

            // задаем начальные значения для DateTimePicker
            _dateTimeBeginPriceList = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            _dateTimeEndPriceList =  new DateTime(2016, 05, 28);

            _displayRadioButton = true;

            _contentButtonDisplaySearch = "Найти";

            this._view.SetDataContext(this);
            this._view.ShowIView();
        }
```

I debugging my code, execution of the programm it does not each Properties ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch

Comment: you mean it doesn't reach to the step `_contentButtonDisplaySearch = "Найти";` ? So where does your code stop. Again you need to change the above line to `ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch= "Найти";`. Set the property not the field to fire PropertyChangedEvent.

Comment: No, contentButtonDisplaySearch = "Найти"; here comes

Comment: when loaded properties content working, but then does not work

Comment: Change the line to `ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch= "Найти";`. Set the property, not the field to fire PropertyChangedEvent.

Comment: ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch= "Найти"; result same

Comment: Also change the method `private void OKRun()`

Comment: private void OKRun()
        {
            //_contentButtonDisplaySearch = "asdasdas";
            ChangeContentButtonDisplaySearch = "dasdas";

            MessageBox.Show("ChangeContent");
         
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94710/discussion-between-niraj-doshi-and-vladimir-kombarov).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple project by analogy with their problem is the same

Models 
Persons.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Annotations;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.Models.Business
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Fields

        private string _firstName;
        private string _middleName;
        private string _lastName;
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
        private Gender _gender;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _firstName) return;
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string MiddleName
        {
            get { return _middleName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _middleName) return;
                _middleName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _lastName) return;
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(_dateOfBirth)) return;
                _dateOfBirth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public Gender Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _gender) return;
                _gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructors

        public Person()
        {

        }

        public Person(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth, Gender gender)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            MiddleName = middleName;
            LastName = lastName;
            DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            Gender = gender;
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged

    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}
```

**PersonModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Models.Business;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        #region Constructors

        public PersonModel()
        {

        }

        #endregion Constructors)

        #region Methods

        public List<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            return new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("Алексей", "Алексеевич", "Алексеев", new DateTime(1980, 5, 10), Gender.Male),
                new Person("Петр", "Петрович", "Петров", new DateTime(1977, 9, 21), Gender.Male),
                new Person("Виктория", "Викторовна", "Викторова", new DateTime(1991, 1, 7), Gender.Female)
            };
        }

        #endregion Methods

    }
}
```

ViewModels

IViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.ViewModels
{
    public interface IViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

PersonsViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Common.Commands;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Models;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Models.Business;
using Learn.MVVM.Example.Views;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonsViewModel<TViewType> : IViewModel where TViewType : IView, new()
    {
        private readonly IView _view;
        private readonly PersonModel _model;

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand OkCommand { get; private set; }

        private string _str;

        public PersonsViewModel()
        {
            this._view = new TViewType();
            this._model = new PersonModel();
            this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(this._model.GetPersons());
            this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand(o => this.OKRun());

            _str = "Кнопка";


            this._view.SetDataContext(this);
            this._view.ShowView();


        }


        public string Str
        {
            get { return _str; }
            set
            {
                if (_str == value)
                    return;
                _str = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Str");

            }


        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        private void OKRun()
        {
            _str = "Change";
        }
    }
}
```

View

IView.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.Views
{
    public interface IView
    {
        void ShowView();
        void ShowViewAsModal();
        void SetDataContext(object dataContext);
    }
}
```

PersonsView.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для PersonsView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PersonsView: IView
    {
        public PersonsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ShowView()
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        public void ShowViewAsModal()
        {
            this.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void SetDataContext(object dataContext)
        {
            this.DataContext = dataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

PersonsView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Learn.MVVM.Example.Views.PersonsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="PersonsView" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Str, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding Str}" Name="OKButton"  Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Commands

RelayCommands.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Learn.MVVM.Example.Common.Commands
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Predicate<object> canExecute;
        private Action<object> execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }

            if (canExecute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("canExecute");
            }

            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute != null && canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }

        private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

        public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var handler = CanExecuteChangedInternal;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public void Destroy()
        {
            canExecute = _ => false;
            execute = _ => { };
        }

        private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the right answer

**ViewModel**

I forgot add INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class PriceListViewModels<TViewType> : **INotifyPropertyChanged**, IViewModel where TViewType : IView,  new ()
```

Thank you all who tried to help